# How can I add a check mark to a link that was visited (the link expands a paragraph, check means "done with reading it")?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, visited

Here is the code that I am trying to improve

http://jsbin.com/cexixamuma/edit?html,output

The links are foldable, they fold when the user clicks on them. 
Mu understanding is that the a:visited css is not honored by the newer browsers for privacy reasons. 
I would like to give to my readers the option to check mark a like (✔) when they are done with the topic but my problem is that the when the user clicks on the link (line) the event is already used to fold, unfold the line What other options do I have?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.toggleDiv = function(divId) {
  var ele = document.getElementById(divId);
  var state=jQuery(ele).is(':visible');
  jQuery(ele).toggle();
  state=jQuery(ele).is(':visible');
  localStorage.setItem( divId, state);  
}


</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".collapsible").each(function(index) {
                      if (typeof($(this).attr('id'))!="undefined") {
                        id=$(this).attr('id');
                        var state = localStorage.getItem(id);
                        ele = document.getElementById(id);
                        if (state=="true") {
                          ele.style.display = 'block' ;}
                        else {
                          ele.style.display = 'none'; }

                      }
                      });
    });
})(jQuery)
</script>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://aa4d96bd21c195e7b862b851b0818e89fb8ee102.googledrive.com/host/0B77cxO0Vjbb2MlYyUFpmVXhTUWc/knowledgetree.css" />

    <a class="ConceptLevel1" href="javascript:toggleDiv('PktS/h+L5EeSqM/4hMH9JA==');" style="font-

size:13pt">Root</a><br>
    <div class="collapsible" style="display:none " id="PktS/h+L5EeSqM/4hMH9JA==">
        <a class="ConceptLevel2" href="javascript:toggleDiv('KlHtq+Xe60essn+0zs9E6g==');" style="font-

size:12pt">level 1</a><br>
        <div class="collapsible" style="" id="KlHtq+Xe60essn+0zs9E6g==">
            <div>Level 2</div>
            <a class="ConceptLevel3" href="javascript:toggleDiv('EdMUp+28okWIWHVbvUaU1g==');" style="font-

size:11pt">Level 2</a><br>
            <div class="collapsible" style="" id="EdMUp+28okWIWHVbvUaU1g==">
                <a class="ConceptLevel4" href="javascript:toggleDiv('wIZCSCx/Xk2YShMAkF33Pg==');" 

style="font-size:10pt">Level 3</a><br>
                <div class="collapsible" style="" id="wIZCSCx/Xk2YShMAkF33Pg==">
                    <div>Level 4</div>
                    <a class="ConceptLevel5" href="javascript:toggleDiv('7GKbN5XRqkybT

+XsbHkyqw==');" style="font-size:9pt">Level 4</a><br>
                    <div class="collapsible" style="" id="7GKbN5XRqkybT+XsbHkyqw==">
                        <div>Level 5</div>
                        <a class="ConceptLevel6" href="javascript:toggleDiv

('rV75pTUXp0KP6Mx6EJznDg==');" style="font-size:8pt">Level 5</a><br>
                        <div class="collapsible" style="display:none " 

id="rV75pTUXp0KP6Mx6EJznDg==">
                        <div class="details">Conclusion: for all the below levels ....</div>
                            <a class="ConceptLevel7" href="javascript:toggleDiv

('a5qCUDoqI0CPlS4pPGcODQ==');" style="font-size:7pt">Level 6</a><br>
                            <div class="collapsible" style="" 

id="a5qCUDoqI0CPlS4pPGcODQ==">
                                <div>Level 7</div>
                                <div>Level 7</div>
                            </div>
                            <div>Level 6</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>Level 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Update: I ended up using dblclick for marking the paragraph as done**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you need to add a class for the visited links? With jQuery that would be: .addClass().

Comment: There is probably many ways to add the check mark but my question is what event should control that since the "onclick" is already taken?

Comment: You can use .on("click") multiple times or .on('click', '.class', function(event){ do something;  do something; }); or in JavaScript addEventListener can handle multiple functions

Comment: The problem is that the two functions (collapse the topic and check the topic ) must be independent from each other they should not require any other user interaction other than the click
If I tie the two above mentioned functions to "onclick" the topic will fold/unfold while the user attempts to check mark the topic

Comment: Wouldn't this be enough: $(your element - link).click(function(){  if(!$(this ).hasClass( "visited" )){ $(this).addClass("visited")};  other function; });

Comment: I think that using dblclick will help me to separate the two as needed. However I will mark your answer as valid since it helped me with the class ideea